# regex for checking the format of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

regex always making me struggle.. what i want here is i have to check whether a string is in the given format in js.

```
{word}/numbers  operator {word}/numbers operator {word}/numbers 

Eg : {VAT}+50+{tax}-20
```

**Note** :

- words always should be wrapped with `{}` (curly brackets)
- number of operations is unlimited
- only arithmetic operators

and it will be more appreciated if someone `suggest any website or something that i can get easy with regex` in future.. thanku :)

Comment: What are the possible operators?

Comment: @sshashank124 sorry... only arithmetic operators

Comment: You have to __specify__ does the binary operator `<<` count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
/^((?:{[a-z]+})|\d+)([+*/-]((?:{[a-z]+})|\d+))*$/i.test("{VAT}+50+{tax}-20")
```

In this regex are included following operators: `+*/-`

Answer (score 1):

The following `regex` also works for **any** length:

`^((\{\[a-zA-Z0-9]\}|\d+)([+\-\*\/]|$))+$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/hV1hL1

Comment: This will match `{1_a_}+`